# Remove duplicates in sequence based on keys

Tags: mysql, duplication

I am looking to remove duplicates on a row by row comparison based on keys Member and Group and data sorted ASC on Member, Group and StartDate. Just return the records in the select query and not delete in the table.

I am basically looking at a row by row comparison to eliminate the duplicates based on the 2 keys and value of the Status column with the data sorted by Member, Group and Start_date.

Sample data:

```
Member  Group   Status        Start_date        End Date
1         2     Active       4/12/2011 01:19    NULL
1         2     Active       4/12/2011 02:19    NULL
1         2     Inactive     4/12/2011 03:19    NULL
1         2     Inactive     4/15/2011 04:19    NULL
1         2     Inactive     4/16/2011 05:19    NULL
1         2     Pending      4/16/2011 11:23    NULL
1         2     Active       4/16/2011 11:25    NULL
1         2     Pending      4/16/2011 11:27    NULL
11        22    Inactive     4/16/2011 11:27    NULL
```

Expected Output:

```
Member  Group   Status        Start_date        End Date
1         2     Active       4/12/2011 01:19    NULL
1         2     Inactive     4/12/2011 03:19    NULL
1         2     Pending      4/16/2011 11:23    NULL
1         2     Active       4/16/2011 11:25    NULL
1         2     Pending      4/16/2011 11:27    NULL
11        22    Inactive     4/16/2011 11:27    NULL
```

DDL and DML:

```
CREATE TABLE `temp1` (
  `MEMBER_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `GROUPIE_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `STATUS` varchar(12) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `START_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Insert into temp1(Member_id, Groupie_id, Status,Start_date, End_Date ) 
values (1,2,'Active', '2011-04-12 01:19:51 PM', NULL);
Insert into temp1(Member_id, Groupie_id, Status,Start_date, End_Date ) 
values (1,2,'Active', '2011-04-12 02:19:51 PM', NULL);
Insert into temp1(Member_id, Groupie_id, Status,Start_date, End_Date ) 
values (1,2,'InActive', '2011-04-12 03:19:51 PM', NULL);
Insert into temp1(Member_id, Groupie_id, Status,Start_date, End_Date ) 
values (1,2,'InActive', '2011-04-15 04:19:51 PM', NULL);
Insert into temp1(Member_id, Groupie_id, Status,Start_date, End_Date ) 
values (1,2,'InActive', '2011-04-16 05:19:51 PM', NULL);
Insert into temp1(Member_id, Groupie_id, Status,Start_date, End_Date ) 
values (1,2,'Pending', '2011-04-16 06:23:51 PM', NULL);
Insert into temp1(Member_id, Groupie_id, Status,Start_date, End_Date ) 
values (1,2,'Active', '2011-04-16 07:25:51 PM', NULL);
Insert into temp1(Member_id, Groupie_id, Status,Start_date, End_Date ) 
values (1,2,'Pending', '2011-04-16 08:27:51 PM', NULL);
Insert into temp1(Member_id, Groupie_id, Status,Start_date, End_Date ) 
values (1,2,'InActive', '2011-04-17 09:27:51 PM', NULL);
Insert into temp1(Member_id, Groupie_id, Status,Start_date, End_Date ) 
values (11,22,'Active', '2011-04-12 01:19:51 PM', NULL);
Insert into temp1(Member_id, Groupie_id, Status,Start_date, End_Date ) 
values (11,23,'InActive', '2011-04-13 02:19:51 PM', NULL);
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you insert duplicate data (i.e. the second record is the same as the first but with a different date)? Can you not just update the time on the original record? Just helps me understand better

Comment: The `INSERT` statements do not match exactly the Sample Data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on consecutive `Start_date` for each partition (on `Member`):

```
SELECT `Member`, `Group`, `Status`, `Start_date`, `End Date`
FROM (
    SELECT @row := CASE WHEN @status=Status AND @member=Member AND @group = `Group`
        THEN @row + 1 ELSE 1 END as row
        , @member:=Member as Member
        , @group:=`Group` as `Group`
        , @status:=Status as Status
        , `Start_date`, `End Date`
    FROM data d
        , (SELECT @row := 0, @status := '', @member := 0, @group := 0) v
    ORDER BY Member, `Group`, Start_date
) as n
WHERE row = 1
ORDER BY Member, Start_date
;
```

Sample [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d1ee/11).

The behavior of this query is similar to the `ROW_NUMBER()`  available in [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) (>= 10g), [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html) (>= 8.4) and [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) (>= 2012).

**Notes on Partitions:**

- This query and [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d1ee/11) partition by `Members` and order `Status` by `Members` and `Start_date`.
- Partition can be remove by removing `@member=Member` from `CASE`
- Partition can be added or set by both `Members` and `Group` like this ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d1ee/10)):

  - Add a test on `@group = 'group'` to the `CASE`
  - Add `@group := 'Group' as 'Group'` in the inner `SELECT` [n]
  - Add `@group := 0` in the variable `SELECT` [v]
  - Add `Group` to `ORDER BY` clauses

In term of performance, an index matching the order and columns used in the `ORDER BY` and `CASE` is very likely needed.

**Output:**

```
Member  | Group     | Status    | Start_date                | End Date
1       | 2         | Active    | April, 12 2011 03:19:00   | (null)
1       | 2         | Inactive  | April, 12 2011 05:19:00   | (null)
1       | 2         | Pending   | April, 16 2011 13:23:00   | (null)
1       | 2         | Active    | April, 16 2011 13:25:00   | (null)
1       | 2         | Pending   | April, 16 2011 13:27:00   | (null)
11      | 22        | Inactive  | April, 16 2011 13:27:00   | (null)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to be efficient but I doubt there's any really efficient way to perfrom this in MySQL:

```
select t.*
from temp1 as t
where not ( t.status <=>
            ( select p.status
              from temp1 as p
              where p.member_id = t.member_id
                and p.groupie_id = t.groupie_id
                and p.start_date < t.start_date
              order by p.start_date desc
              limit 1
            )
          ) ;
```

Test in [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42fbb3/3).

It's one of the rare cases where a solution using variables, like Julien's answer is likely to perfrom better with a proper index, doing only a full index scan.

The index you'd need is on `(member_id, groupie_id, start_date, status, end_date)`, with either query (mine or Julien's).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could filter the start_date with MAX or MIN and group by member, group, status, and start_date

Comment: Please consider expanding your answer and explaining in more detail how this will solve the OP's problem.